# How to pass path variable in thymeleaf to display data from connected table

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have two tables: `User` and `Wallet`. This is how `Wallet` looks like:

[image]

As you can see I can assignee wallet to user.

Now, I want to create a controller that will show `initial_balance` and `wallet_name` in `HTML`.

This is how my controller now looks:

```
 @GetMapping("/userWallet/balance/{user_id}")
 public String getUserWallet(@PathVariable(value = "user_id") Long user_id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("wallet", walletService.findByUserId(user_id));
    return "userProfile";
 }
```

And that works fine, when I go to that URL and pass `user_id` I get his `initialBalance`, but I need to go to that URL every time manually.

So, I tried to create this in `HTML`:

```
<div th:each="wallet : ${wallet}">
<a th:href="@{/api/wallet/userWallet/balance/{user_id}(user_id = ${wallet.id})}">
    <span th:text="${wallet.initialBalance}"></span>
</a>
</div>
```

But it still wont to show me initialBalance of current user on page. Any help?

Comment: Does your controller have a @RequestMapping("/api/wallet") on it? Can you show us the URL that's generated by hovering over one of the links? What is being presented when you click on the link?

Comment: Hi, I managed to fix the problem with `long userId = user.getId();` and then pass that `userId` at the end of URL. I have just one question before I post new question because I got a new problem, for example If I have more then one wallet on one user I got error `query did not return a unique result` that is because on my repo is `Wallet` instead of `List<Wallet>` but when I set `List<Wallet>` I'm getting wallets from all user instead of wallets just from userId that is logged like I used to get when there is just one wallet per user

Comment: You will need to post your current controller, repository, and entity code.